# how can i remove underline in link

Tags: html, css

i am working on a project in which i have to make a webpage .i have some links for going web sites and i want to remove underline in link ( `a` ).
please help me.

```html
      <a href="google.com" >google</a><br>
      <a href="youtup.com" >youtup</a><br>
      <a href="owerstackflow.com" >stackoverflow</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://Example.Microsoft.Com">nonunderlinedhyperlink</a>
```

Comment: tag a is block level or inline level and i want to underline show when i put mouse in hover of link